# Specflow tests all run twice

Tags: resharper, specflow

I'm using Specflow with NUnit and WatiN to do some acceptance testing, and all my specflow tests run twice. Since they're using WatiN to browse around my site, it takes  a considerable amount of extra time.

I only have a basic specflow feature so far - basically I took the example feature, changed some names and implemented the steps.

Why do all tests run twice?

Edit: Perhaps I should add that I'm using the R# test runner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have Gallio installed? It can register itself to run nunit tests as well as resharper's built in runner, so tests do get run twice. You can choose which runner you want in ReSharper's options

Comment: That was it - thanks a lot! I never would have spotted that one =)

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have Gallio installed. I have as dependencies MSTest and xUnit though. But my `App.Config` clearly says SpecRun is the `unitTestProvider`.